# Displacement Modifier Leaves 0 Height Around 2 Edges of Plane when Applied

Tags: modifiers, displacement

Good evening,

I am working on creating terrain using planes, a greyscale Heightmap and the displace modifier.  Everything is working wonderfully with the exception on a "Lip" I guess it could be called, being left around the edges of each terrain I import.

[image: Here the vertical side facing us, that should not be.]

[image: The side with no vertical edge, that is how it should be.]

The heightmap is set to clip, the terrain is non-square, so it is mapped to the UV.

These pieces are all cut from the one massive terrain that I am breaking into individual screens and I need these edges to match up for when I pull it all into Unity.

Thank you very much for any assistance with this.

Comment: there is likely a series of pixels on the edge of the height map that are a different color. You can try scaling the UV map to get rid of those edges.

Comment: I did not see any kind of extra pixels along the edges of the HM I am using.